# Python/Tkinter: running an external app with subprocess causes tkinter to become disabled

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

The following very simple code (Windows) plays an mp4 movie file using subprocess and the Media Player Classic portable version.

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x500")

mpcpath = 'MPC-BEPortable.exe'
moviepath = "filename.mp4"

def PlayMovie():
    subprocess.call([mpcpath, moviepath])

PlayButton = tk.Button(root,text="play")
PlayButton.config(command=PlayMovie)
PlayButton.place(x=50,y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

It works perfectly. However, while the movie is playing, Tkinter is in a disabled state. That is, if you try to interact with the Tkinter app, Windows sends an error saying that the app is not responding. Is there a way (using subprocess or some other method) to have the media player go off and run in some other thread, and leave the Tkinter application operational?

Comment: tkinter is single threaded. You'll need to move the call to a thread or separate process.

Comment: Could you please explain how I might do that? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `subprocess.call()`.